# Responsive Design Mode vs Resizing browser window

Tags: html, css, browser, responsive-design, resolution

I am trying to change things depending on resolution. So I use for exemple:

```
    @mediaquery only screen and (min-width:1125px) and (max-width:1280px) {
      flex-basis: 31.4rem;
    }
```

It works perfectly in the responsive design mode of Mozilla Firefox, but when I am resizing the browser window directly it changes only from 1262px instead of 1280px and so between 1263px and 1280px it does not change. It actually does that for any media query (instead of 560px like in responsive mode it changes only from 540px for example).

Any idea where it could originate from ? How do I unify values from browser resizing and Responsive design mode ?

Comment: Sounds like a scrollbar-dependent issue - 18 to 19 pixels is the usual scrollbar with on most desktop systems. Mobile is different, because there the scrollbar width is usually not subtracted from the available content width, bus just laid “on top” of it.

Answer (score 1):

When you are testing the page with any responsive tool it's not counting the vertical scrollbar of the page. But when you actually resize the browser, it will give around `20px` width difference, which is because of browser's default scrollbar width.

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly it ! Don't know why I didn't think of it sooner. It's precisely 18px for me at least so I just changed for resolutions superior to 1080 to account for the scroll bar.

Comment: @MrKayako, If my answer helps you, you can appreciate it by marking it done with a vote.